# Create New related record in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

I have a custom object `AP_Customer_Address__c` which has a lookup relationship to `Contact`. I have an LWC on the contact record page which allows the creation of a new address for that contact. I use `NavigationMixin.Navigate` to create new address records. When I try to create an address, it asks me to select a contact. I want the contact to be auto-filled and read-only. I tried adding the contact's `record Id` in `state` and `attributes`, but it's not working.

Please guide. Thanks!

**LWC Screenshot**
[image: LWC Screenshot]

**Auto Fill contact name using Contact ID**
[image: Auto Fill contact name]

**Code**

```js
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__objectPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: this.recordId, //added record Id here
                    objectApiName: 'AP_Customer_Address__c',
                    actionName: 'new'
                },
                state: {
                    recordId: this.recordId //added record Id here
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-population is yet not supported in Lightning Web component yet for **NavigationMixin** functionality. I have raised an issue and an idea a long back. Yet it has not been delivered.

1. [set default value while navigate to new record](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/issues/66)
2. [Allow setting pre-default values in record form by navigation service in LWC](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CYGkQAO)

You need to look for other workarounds like using [Aura component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:createRecord/documentation) or [Lightning Data Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) to open a record form with pre-populated values.

Currently, LWC allows you to just set the recordtype value by default as of now.

```
showNewOpportunityForm(recordTypeId) {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Opportunity',
                actionName: 'new',

            },
            state: {
                recordTypeId: recordTypeId,
            }
        });
    }
```

### Update

In spring 20, this feature has been delivered by Salesforce.

See this [link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lc_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm). According to it, We can do this as follow:-

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'new'                
            },
            state : {
                nooverride: '1',
                defaultFieldValues:"Name=Salesforce,AccountNumber=A1,AnnualRevenue=37000,Phone=7055617159"
            }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported directly in LWC as far as I am aware. However, you can do this using Doug Ayers' [Record Create URL Component](https://github.com/douglascayers/sfdx-record-create-url-component) (an Aura component) that can populate whatever fields you wish to by passing in values for those fields (including the relationship lookup, for example). This is the approach we have used.